# why my array value not able to retrieve and isset doesn't work for me

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a dynamic searching function but there is a problem I am not able to solve.

What's wrong with the following code?

JSON:

```
...
$result=$obj->Decode_Serialize($resource);// method to unserialize string value


$text= isset($result['text_department_code']) ? 
    $result['text_department_code']: 'a';

if(!empty($search) && !empty( $checkbox) && !empty($match) && !empty($sort) && !empty($text))
{
    echo $text= $result['text_department_code'];  // error Notice: Undefined index: text_department_code in line 18
    print $text;
    print_r($result);
}
...
```

I don't know why its just simply not work even isset have been included.
//$result['text_department_code'];

```
print_r($result) output:
Array
(
    [search_deparment_code] => department_code
    [checkbox_deparment_code] => true
    [match_deparment_code] => all
    [sort_deparment_code] => ASC
    [text_deparment_code] => aa
)
```

//Jquery passing serialize string to ajax

```
function getInstantSearchResult(){
    $('#keypress').keyup(function(){      
        var Post_String = $('#forma').serialize();
        //  ajax_get_data(1,st);
        //alert(Post_String);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'jsonAjaxFinder.php',
            data : {Query_String:Post_String},
            success : function(value){
                alert(value);
                ajax_get_data(1);
            }
        });
    });        
} 
 function ajax_get_data(page){
       var businessUnitRequest;        

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {
         businessUnitRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
       else
       {
         businessUnitRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

        var frame = document.getElementById("frame");  
        frame.style.left='20px';
        var paginations = document.getElementById("pagination");    

        businessUnitRequest.open("POST", "jsonAjaxFinder.php", true);
        businessUnitRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        businessUnitRequest.onreadystatechange = function (){
                 if((businessUnitRequest.readyState == 4) && (businessUnitRequest.status=200))
                 {

                      frame = document.getElementById("frame");  
                       var leng= frame.rows.length;
                      for (z = leng - 1; z > 0; z--){
                         frame.deleteRow(z);            
                       }
                    var d = JSON.parse(businessUnitRequest.responseText);
                    for(var o in d){
                        var row = frame.insertRow(1);
                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

                        cell1.style.paddingLeft='15%';
                        cell2.style.paddingLeft='1%';
                        cell1.innerHTML=  d[o].department_code;
                        cell2.innerHTML= d[o].description;
                    }    

                 }
        }

             businessUnitRequest.send('no_page='+parseInt(page));
             //+'&serialize='+ serialize
             businessUnitRequest.innerHTML="requesting....";
    }
```

Can someone explain to me my problem because i don't know how to solve it? that

Comment: Hi there! That sure is a lot of code you posted... A little too much to just be able to read and understand in this format. Would it be possible for you to post only the relevant code? Try to narrow the problem and only post the relevant code.

Comment: hi ....sry about that i will change it soon since i scared that something i did mistake

Comment: Oh wow.. you even added more... ok then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your var_dump you provided and compare it to your code. You have typos...

```
print_r($result) output:
Array
(
    [search_deparment_code] => department_code
    [checkbox_deparment_code] => true
    [match_deparment_code] => all
    [sort_deparment_code] => ASC
    [text_deparment_code] => aa
)
```

You have "Deparment" in the dump and "department" in the array indexes.

Essentially, all of your if(isset()) lines are returning false.

Comment: hi @Robert allow me to confirm that because i not sure what u trying to pointed out the following is my var_dump output. do you mean that typos error is related to the case sensitive of arrayindexes 

  ["search_deparment_code"]=>
  string(15) "department_code"
  ["checkbox_deparment_code"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["match_deparment_code"]=>
  string(3) "all"
  ["sort_deparment_code"]=>
  string(3) "ASC"
  ["text_deparment_code"]=>
  string(2) "aa"
}

Comment: ^^^ not sure what your saying.. Other than what I already pasted. Maybe explain away this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here?

```
echo $search = $result['text_department_code'];
```

If you want to echo whether or not $search matches $result[...], do this:

```
echo $search == $result['text_department_code'];
```

If you want to store $result[...] in $search and echo whether or not it fails, you'll have to check if $result[...] is set again:

```
echo (isset($result['text_department_code']) && $search = $result['text_department_code']);
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this helps, but in the if statement u referenced `$result['text_department_code']` but it should be `$text`

```
if(!empty($search) && !empty( $checkbox) && !empty($match) && !empty($sort) && !empty($text))
{
    echo $search = $text;
    print $search;
    print_r($result);
}
```